# Pandas groupby day in range and category

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe in the following format and want to sum the weight column by category and by day (where day is in the start-end range)

i.e. from this:

| batch | category | start_day | end_day | duration | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX001 | AAA | 2022-01-06 | 2022-01-14 | 6 | 0.1250 |
| XX002 | BBB | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-12 | 4 | 0.2500 |
| XX003 | AAA | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-09 | 2 | 0.5000 |

to this:

| day | AAA | BBB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-06 | 0.1250 | 0.0000 |
| 2022-01-07 | 0.6250 | 0.0000 |
| 2022-01-08 | 0.6250 | 0.2500 |
| 2022-01-09 | 0.1250 | 0.2500 |
| 2022-01-10 | 0.1250 | 0.2500 |
| 2022-01-11 | 0.1250 | 0.2500 |
| 2022-01-12 | 0.1250 | 0.0000 |
| 2022-01-13 | 0.1250 | 0.0000 |

I can foresee some ways of doing it inefficiently by e.g. generating a series of days from earliest to latest, then iterating over each entry in the individual table to increment the sum of weights in each category in each day, but I'm guessing there's a better way of doing it using groupby, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

EDIT: Here's a loop-heavy way of doing it:

```
import pandas as pd

batches_data = {
    "XX001": {"category": "AAA", "start_day": pd.Timestamp("2022-01-06"), "end_day": pd.Timestamp("2022-01-14")},
    "XX002": {"category": "BBB", "start_day": pd.Timestamp("2022-01-08"), "end_day": pd.Timestamp("2022-01-12")},
    "XX003": {"category": "AAA", "start_day": pd.Timestamp("2022-01-07"), "end_day": pd.Timestamp("2022-01-09")},
}
batches = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(batches_data, orient="index")
batches["duration"] = (batches["end_day"] - batches["start_day"]).dt.days
batches["weight"] = 1 / batches["duration"]

min_start = min(batches["start_day"])
max_end = max(batches["end_day"])

dates = pd.date_range(start=min_start, end=max_end, freq='D')
categories = sorted(batches["category"].unique())

daily_weights_by_category = pd.DataFrame(0, index=dates, columns=categories)
for _, batch in batches.iterrows():
    for date in dates:
        if date >= batch["start_day"] and date < batch["end_day"]:
            daily_weights_by_category.loc[date, batch["category"]] += batch["weight"]

print(daily_weights_by_category)
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

`df.groupby(["category","start_day"]).sum()["weight"]`

1. groupby - groups in to sub dfs and you can actually iterate these with

```
for grouped_df, name in df.groupby(["category","start_day"]):

    print(name)
```

2. `.sum()` then sum the column
3. `["weight"]` select the weight column

should work (not tested but pretty sure thats right - its been a while)